# Sorting strings in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a number of file paths into elastic search without without setting any mappings, so I'm letting elasticsearch detect the field types. It has detected this field as {"type" : "string"} which would appear to be ok. The file paths are:

```
/file/file1
/file/file2
/file/file5
/file/file3
/file/file4
```

When I do a query and tell it to sort on the file path, the file paths are returned in their original order and it appears that they all receive the same sort value. Is this an issue caused by not setting a mapping? How can I get elasticsearch to sort these values in the correct order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try mapping that filed to be

```
{
    "type":  "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to apply that mapping, however I get an error that "merge failed with failures {[mapper [filepath] has different [index] values"  and that the merge failed and I cannot changed from disabled to enabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: I deleted the index, applied the mapping and now it works great! I thought it was possible to modify the mapping with data already loaded, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: Yeah it is possible but you have to close your index first then you can change the mapping. However, the moment you are closing your index, no query can be apply means it is the same like you delete the index and re-create it. It's just faster to close and re-open in fact